# Pulldown doesn't seem to affect inverter?

Tags: relay, inverter, pulldown

I have a relay/optoisolator circuit which is connected to a microcontroller.

The input/output is controlled by a physical slide switch.

I expected this to turn off the relay and status light because of the 10K pulldown, but the status LED stays on when I switch to the input side.

What am I missing?

The relay is a [SIP-1A05](http://aitendo3.sakura.ne.jp/aitendo_data/product_img/wireless/SIP-1A05/SIP-1A05.pdf).

[image: The Circuit]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are actually using an original, old, 7406, or a 74LS06, the 10K resistor is much too high to produce a logic Low.  Bipolar TTL inputs source current, so a pull-down resistor must be a low enough value to draw about 1 mA when dropping less than 0.8 volts to produce a Low.  Traditionally, we would use a switch to ground to guarantee a Low, and a 5K or so pull-up resistor to guarantee a high, although an open input would normally be recognized as a High.

A CMOS part (74HC06, 74AC06, etc.) has a very high input impedance and neither sources or sinks any significant current so would work in your circuit.